# Is it academic dishonesty if I committed my exam answers into a private GitHub repo during an exam?

Tags: exams, cheating, code

During an exam, I committed codes into my repository on GitHub.

In this case, am I involved in academic dishonesty for providing answers in public even though my repository was set as private?

Comment: Did you give anyone else access to your GitHub account?

Answer (score 2):

If you were setting the access to be limited to only you, then you did not share your code. It is not different from saving your code on a USB.

Intent and motivation enter the picture here. If by accident you made your code public during the exam, you would have only be engaged in academic dishonesty if you intended it to be used by other students.

It also seems unlikely that someone would have noticed your upload.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't make the answers public. But it is likely that you did break some other rule.

Read the rules of the university to find whether you broke a rule. And you should probably delete the code from Github.

Comment: Why delete the code from Github? (assuming no rules were violated).

Comment: @GoodDeeds Did the instructors intentionally release the exam questions or answers in a public format? If not then keeping a copy is about the same as taking a picture of the exam to sneak to friends in future years.

Answer (score -3):

First of all: Depending in which country you live in, that code of yours is protected by copyright law and is yours. You may be free to publish, sell or license it.

However, I am not sure, if you were allowed to use any external sources during your examination (if it was a take-home-exam, probably yes).

In my experience as a university teacher for 7 years (although a very different field): as long as you don't post "this is the answer to the exam question X", there should not be a problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community  What is unclear in this answer?